# Is it possible to increase the number of disks a VM can have?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

A Standard_d4s_v3 node comes with a limitation of a maximum of just 8 disks can be attached. Is it possible to increase this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot increase the number of disks which can be attached to a specific VM size. If you would like more disks, then you will need to increase the size of your VM so it supports more disks.